MINGW32-MAKE: *** No rule to make target '*.cpp.o', needed by 'module.dll'. Stop
I am trying to compile both C and C++ files into a DLL using a makefile but whenever I build I get the error MINGW32-MAKE: *** No rule to make target 'vendor\whatever*.cpp.o', needed by 'module.dll'.  Stop.
All the files in the main source folder compile properly.
Im pretty sure the issue is with how I get all the .o files with patsubst and subst but I am unsure on how to fix it.
I know this is dumb but I have never used makefiles before.
.PHONY: build clean mkdir run print

CC     := gcc.exe
CXX    := g++.exe

CWD    := $(subst \,/,$(shell cd))
SRCDIR := $(CWD)/src
INCDIR := $(CWD)/inc
BINDIR := $(CWD)/build

SRC_C   := $(shell dir /a:-d /b/s $(shell cd)\src\\*.c)
SRC_C   := $(subst \,/,$(SRC_C))
CCFLAGS := -O2 -I "$(CWD)/vendor" -I "$(CWD)/inc"

LDLIBS  := -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -ldwmapi -ld3d11 -ldxgi -ldxguid -lgid32 -ld3dcompiler
LDFLAGS := -s -shared -mconsole -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
EXE     := module.dll

OBJECTS := $(SRC_C)
OBJECTS := $(subst \,/,$(OBJECTS))
OBJECTS := $(subst /src,,$(patsubst $(CWD)/%.c,$(BINDIR)/int/%.c.o,$(OBJECTS)))

build: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

$(CWD)/int/%.c.o: $(SRC_C)/%.c
    $(shell echo $<)
    $(CC) -c -std=c99 $(CCFLAGS) -o $< $@

Edit: Simplified the makefile with the same issue

GNU Make is a POSIX tool, although it is ported to run on Windows.  It doesn't support Windows path formats.  You should always use forward slashes (/) in your makefiles for directory separators, never backslashes (\).  Almost all Windows facilities support forward slashes as well.  The only ones that don't are cmd.com builtin commands, like rmdir etc.

I have changed a bunch of stuff to use / instead of \ but now it just skips building the object files @MadScientist

Most likely you didn't change enough things, or changed them incorrectly, so now the OBJECTS variable is empty.  You can add $(info OBJECTS is '$(OBJECTS)') to the makefile after you've set it, and it will print the value.  You can use $(info ...) to print the value of other variables.  If the variable is empty, then $(EXE): $(OBJECTS) expands to just module.dll: and there are no prerequisites listed, so make doesn't build them.

@MadScientist I will update my post with something more simple showing what I done so far.

The rule of thumb is for writing sane cross-platform makefiles is to use forward slashes everywhere, and to make sure you're using sh as the shell rather than cmd (which should happen automatically as long as it's in PATH, which should happen automatically if you installed Make from MSYS2).

@HolyBlackCat As of now I dont plan on building for anything other than windows as its the only operating system I have and its not a public project.

You should examine the value of the SRC_C and OBJECTS variables, they are probably not right.  You need to get those correct before the makefile will work.

Also: you should not ever use $(shell ...) inside a recipe (e.g., $(shell echo $<).  A recipe is running in a shell already, so it's useless and can lead to confusing results (not in this specific case).  Just write echo $<.  But you don't even need that since $< is already part of the compile line so you can just see what it is from that.

One more thing: make does not work with pathnames containing whitespace.  You must avoid paths containing spaces if you want to use make.

@MadScientist The variables seem right,
SRC_C shows   X:/source/local/codblops3_clean/src/entrypoint.c
OBJECTS shows X:/source/local/codblops3_clean/build/int/entrypoint.c.o

In that case I can only assume that those object files are already existing, so make decided it doesn't need to rebuild them.  That is, after all, make's entire purpose.  If you don't think so you should use make -d and look through the output for why make decides to not build those files.

After that im even more confused, It couldnt find the rule to build so i modified it and now it tries to make makefile.o

So I fixed it myself after a few hours of testing stuff.
I took a template makefile and modified it to suit what I need
.DEFAULT_GOAL = build

CC  = gcc
CXX = g++
LD  = g++

CCFLAGS = -O2 -I"vendor" -I"inc"
LDFLAGS = -s -shared -mconsole -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
LDLIBS  = 

ifeq ($(RENDERER),d3d11)
    CCFLAGS := $(CCFLAGS) -DRENDERER_USE_DIRECTX11
    LDLIBS  := $(LDLIBS) -ld3d11 -ldxgi -ldxguid -ld3dcompiler
endif
ifeq ($(RENDERER),d3d12)
    CCFLAGS = $(CCFLAGS) -DRENDERER_USE_DIRECTX12
endif
ifeq ($(RENDERER),glfw)
    CCFLAGS := $(CCFLAGS) -DRENDERER_USE_GLFW
endif

SRCDIR = src
SRC_FILES := $(subst \,/, $(shell dir /a:-d /b/s $(shell cd)\src\\*.c)) $(subst \,/, $(shell dir /a:-d /b/s $(shell cd)\src\\*.cc))

ifeq ($(BACKEND),imgui)
    SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES) $(subst \,/, $(shell dir /a:-d /b/s vendor\imgui\src\*.cpp))
    CCFLAGS   := $(CCFLAGS) -DRENDERER_USE_IMGUI
    LDLIBS    := $(LDLIBS) -lgdi32 -luser32 -ldwmapi
endif
ifeq ($(BACKEND),nuklear)
    SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES) $(subst \,/, $(shell dir /a:-d /b/s vendor\nuklear\src\*.c))
    CCFLAGS += -DRENDERER_USE_NUKLEAR
endif
SRC_FILES := $(subst $(subst \,/,$(shell cd))/,, $(SRC_FILES))

INTDIR = build/int
INT_FILES := $(SRC_FILES)
INT_FILES := $(patsubst %.cc, $(INTDIR)/%.o, $(INT_FILES))
INT_FILES := $(patsubst %.c, $(INTDIR)/%.o, $(INT_FILES))
INT_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(INTDIR)/%.o, $(INT_FILES))
INT_FILES := $(subst src/,, $(INT_FILES))

OUTDIR = build/bin
OUT_FILE = module.dll

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo $(SRC_FILES)
    @echo $(INT_FILES)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(INT_FILES)
    $(RM) $(OUTDIR)/$(EXE)

.PHONY: build
build: $(OUTDIR)/$(OUT_FILE)

$(OUTDIR)/$(OUT_FILE): $(INT_FILES)
     $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(INT_FILES) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

$(INTDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
$(INTDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/%.cc
    $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
$(INTDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(INTDIR)/vendor/nuklear/%.o:   vendor/nuklear/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(INTDIR)/vendor/imgui/%.o: vendor/imgui/src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

-include $(DEPENDS)

I know its probably bad code but it works so :p
